# Linking to image in sdcard PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a saved image in android "mnt/sdcard/offlineImages" folder. The image is named img_0.jpg.

Now I want to display this image on a html page via javascript.

I tried the following two cases.

**CASE ONE WHICH WORKS.**

```
html
<img id="anImg" />

javaScript
document.getElementById('anImg').src = "file:///mnt/sdcard/offlineImages/img_0.jpg";
```

**CASE TWO, WHICH DOESN'T WORK.**

```
html
<div id="img_wrap"></div>

javascript
var anImg = new Image();
anImg.src = "file:///mnt/sdcard/offlineImages/img_0.jpg";
document.getElementById("img_wrap").appendChild(anImg);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var anImg= document.createElement('img');
anImg.src = "file:///mnt/sdcard/offlineImages/img_0.jpg"; 
anImg.width="200px"; // consider adding width
anImg.height="150px";  // consider adding height
document.getElementById("img_wrap").appendChild(anImg);
```

Try this

Comment: Well, I am sorry that I didnt mention, But I am adding width and height in percent. Also, I am trying to convert an already working online code into phonegap. and Yes, I should try doing createElement instead of new Image().